# How to install visual studio 2010 in alternate drive?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I'm trying to install VS 2010 on D drive, but when i change the location in the destination field of the installer, it doesn't matter, it still installs it on C. The only thing that went to D was the install log file. Any way around this?

Comment: Is this a clean install?  The installer definitely supports non c:\ drive installations.

Comment: Yes, clean install on W2k8 R2 Server VM.

Comment: May be this http://superuser.com/questions/118359/how-do-i-install-visual-studio-2010-express-somewhere-besides-c help you

Comment: Looks like MS pwned me again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install VS on C: and move it to your any location on D: and make junction to this folder. After that VS will still think that it's location on C:

How to make a junction you can read [here](http://meta-coding.blogspot.com/2011/05/links-to-files-and-directories-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

It should allow the installation of the actual software on different drives, but a lot of its key components (.NET Framework, libraries, etc.) have to go on the C drive. I think ultimately, it puts a lot more on the C drive even if the app itself it installed on a different drive.